# How to change the cursor color in textinputedittext inside textinputlayout

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

[image]

How to change the cursor color of textinputedittext.

I used textcursordrawable but it doesn't work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Change the colorAccent value on your theme.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change only the cursor color, you can use:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout                
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined"
    ....>
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined" parent="">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

[image]

If you want to change the cursor color but also the box, the label..

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks gabrielw mariotti. Its works nice.... thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.10.0 of material-components-android library, you can directly set cursor color.

Just add attributes to your TextInputLayout view:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cursorErrorColor="@color/error_color"
app:cursorColor="@color/accent_color"
...
```